# Inject values into enum

Tags: c++, enums

I have the snippet:

```
enum class EnumClass {
};

constexpr EnumClass m0 = static_cast<EnumClass>(0);
constexpr EnumClass m1 = static_cast<EnumClass>(1);

int main()
{
    EnumClass aa = m0;
    switch (aa) {
        case m0 : break;
        case m1 : break;
    }
}
```

Gcc 7.0 with -Wall flag reasonably warns me:

```
warning: case value '0' not in enumerated type 'EnumClass' [-Wswitch]
warning: case value '1' not in enumerated type 'EnumClass' [-Wswitch]
```

What I want is to get rid of this warning. Suppose there are a lot of such switches so it is not very convenient to manually turn off/on this warning each time. Also I don't want to turn off this diagnostic  globally.

What I want is to say somehow (maybe with some macro in EnumClass definition) to the compiler that any possible int value can be in EnumClass. Can somebody suggest some ideas how it can be achieved?

Comment: What's the point of using an enum if you want it to map to every possible `int` value?

Comment: I'm writing small library for smart enums for private purposes. I don't really use such enum as I wrote in this snippet. It is a simplified example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand what your end goal is, but, assuming that you want to prevent the `-Wswitch` warning from being produced only in some particular parts of your code, you can use `#pragma` directives as follows:

```
int main()
{
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
    EnumClass aa = EnumClass::m0;
    switch (aa) {
        case EnumClass::m0 : break;       
        case EnumClass::m1 : break;       
        case static_cast<EnumClass>(888) : break;
    }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ry8Luc0FboNdD5Z0)

This will not disable `-Wswitch` globally - it will be restored on `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` line.

Comment: No this is too verbose to turn off diagnostic manually in each switch/case. I updated the question. Maybe the design will be more clear.

Comment: @SeleznevAnton: it's not - your usage of `enum class` is unconventional and... wrong. Do you want a "strong typedef" instead?

Comment: I'll take a look at "strong typedefs" discussions. Maybe they will suit me. Thanks.